# Forked private repository, duplicate and make public repository

Tags: github

I have forked a **private repository**, can I duplicate and make a new **public repository** on my github ...?

Comment: why don't you just try it, instead of asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mary, private forks can’t be made public. You can copy to a new repository easily though.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/otherusername/private-repo.git
cd private-repo.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/yourname/public-repo.git
cd ..
rm -rf private-repo.git
git clone https://github.com/yourname/public-repo.git
```